# The argument type 'Response<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String' on Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

i'm trying to put a response (from an api) on a map but i cant make it work.

Heres the code:

```
Map<String, dynamic> map = jsonDecode(response);
```

the "response" word gets red with the error and i cant run the app.

```
The argument type 'Response<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.dartargument_type_not_assignable
```

I have also tried putting response.toString() and the app even runs but i get several errors like

```
E/flutter (10331): #0      _ChunkedJsonParser.fail (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1404:5)
E/flutter (10331): #1      _ChunkedJsonParser.parse (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:934:48)
E/flutter (10331): #2      _parseJson (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:40:10)
```

Can someone help me

The response json is:

```
[
    {
        "Code": 2025,
        "Qty": 4,
        "Desc": "SERVIÇO DE ALINHAR EIXOS",
        "OsNumber": "3862"
    },
    {
        "Code": 204457,
        "Qty": 1,
        "Desc": "SERVIÇO REPARO",
        "OsNumber": "3862"
    }
]
```

Comment: kindly share the response (json) structure

Comment: @Tasnuvaoshin i updated the post

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the method with **(response.body)** instead of just **(response)** . So your code should be:

```
var map = jsonDecode(response.body);
```

Comment: I tried but got another error: The getter 'body' isn't defined for the type 'Response<dynamic>'.
Try importing the library that defines 'body', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'body'.dartundefined_getter

Answer (score 0):

```
  final extractedData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
```

Then

```
final List<product> loadedProducts = [];
      extractedData.forEach((key, value) {
        loadedProducts.add(product(
          id: key,
          title: value['Code'],
          description: value['Qty'],
          price: value['Desc'],
          imageUrl: value['OsNumber'],
        
        ));
```

product is the Model class of your

```
 {
        "Code": 2025,
        "Qty": 4,
        "Desc": "SERVIÇO DE ALINHAR EIXOS",
        "OsNumber": "3862"
    },
```

this Object . So you will get the list of object . so create a Model class for this object and name is product.dart . then the code will work

here is the model for your object

```
class product {
  int code;
  int qty;
  String desc;
  String osNumber;

  product({this.code, this.qty, this.desc, this.osNumber});

  product.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    code = json['Code'];
    qty = json['Qty'];
    desc = json['Desc'];
    osNumber = json['OsNumber'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['Code'] = this.code;
    data['Qty'] = this.qty;
    data['Desc'] = this.desc;
    data['OsNumber'] = this.osNumber;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried but there is a error in the "body" part on the first line you did: "The getter 'body' isn't defined for the type 'Response<dynamic>'.
Try importing the library that defines 'body', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'body'.dartundefined_getter"

Comment: ok you need to add json.decoder library . Import this

Comment: import 'dart:convert

Comment: Then run flutter clean in your terminal then try with my given example it should work

Comment: Still not running, the app doenst even run because of the error on body that i posted above